# Getting typeError for Login screen react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have created Login screen after entering emailID and password user should be able to login and should be able to view VenueList component i.e list of all venues. I am using auth0 for authentication. I am getting type error how can I fix it ?

I have created VenueList component which should be viewable after I enter email and password.

Login.js:

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, TextInput, KeyboardAvoidingView, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
import Auth0 from "react-native-auth0";

var credentials = require('./auth0-credentials');
const auth0 = new Auth0(credentials);

export default class Login extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { accessToken: null };
    }

    _onLogin = () => {
        auth0.webAuth
          .authorize({
            scope: 'openid profile',
            audience: 'https://' + credentials.domain + '/userinfo'
          })
          .then(credentials => {
            Alert.alert(
              'Success',
              'AccessToken: ' + credentials.accessToken,
              [{ text: 'OK', onPress: () => console.log('OK Pressed') }],
              { cancelable: false }
            );
            this.setState({ accessToken: credentials.accessToken });
          })
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
    };

    _onLogout = () => {
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
          this.setState({ accessToken: null });
        } else {
          auth0.webAuth
            .clearSession({})
            .then(success => {
              this.setState({ accessToken: null });
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
        }
    };

    render() {
        let loggedIn = this.state.accessToken === null ? false : true;
            return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.header}>Auth0Sample - Login</Text>
                <Text>
                You are {loggedIn ? '' : 'not '}logged in.
                </Text>
                <Button
                onPress={loggedIn ? this._onLogout : this._onLogin}
                title={loggedIn ? 'Log Out' : 'Log In'}
                />
            </View>
            );
    }

}
```

In auth0-credentials.js:

```
module.exports = {
clientId: "{AUTH0_CLIENT_ID}",
domain: "{AUTH0_DOMAIN}"  
};
```

Screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is probably due to error in linking the library, try performing manual linking

Comment: @PritishVaidya I am new to reactNative what is Manual linking ?

Comment: Here follow the steps in this [link](https://github.com/mCodex/react-native-sensitive-info#manually), rebuild and run

Comment: Probably because the domain name is incorrect or null as seen in screenshot

Comment: @PritishVaidya My domian name is correct. In .env file I have added `AUTH0_DOMAIN="xyz.auth0.com"`

Comment: It doesn't show in the url in the screenshot.

Comment: @PritishVaidya Am I missing something ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179884/discussion-between-fun-joker-and-pritish-vaidya).

Comment: I'm not sure about the issue though since I don't know much about Auth0, the screenshot looks correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
react-native link react-native-sensitive-info
```

Try this command and rebuild